# How do I run a python script as root

Tags: gpio, python

I'm try running a Python script that uses the GPIO pins but I get an error telling me that it doesn't have access to `dev/mem` and I should try running as `root`.

I don't know how to run a Python script as `root`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the terminal instead of doing `python yourProgram.py`, do `sudo python yourProgram.py`. It will ask for your password so type it and it should run.

Of course if it is python3 do `sudo python3 yourProgram.py`